# Getting number of ITEMS in an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, function, parameters, count

I need to insert a string (from one window(QueryBuilder)) into an array(of another window(Main)).

In the Main i have a method as

```
public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
{ 
    int itemsInUserBuiltQueries = UserBuiltQueries.Count();
    UserBuiltQueries[itemsInUserBuiltQueries] = argFromQueryBuilder.ToString();
    //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it.
    foreach (string query in UserBuiltQueries)
    {
        CheckBox checkQueries = new CheckBox() { Content = query };
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(checkQueries);
        checkboxes.Add(checkQueries);
    }
}
```

Where `UserBuiltQueries` is declared as

```
string[] UserBuiltQueries;
```

However when from the other window i do

```
 backscreen.DisplayCalcQuery(ttextBox1.Text.ToString()); //where backscreen is the Main
```

The argument is passed well but i get an error as

```
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: have you initialized?

Comment: It seams does not initialized yet.

Comment: please add stacktrace?

Comment: After initializing, `UserBuiltQueries[itemsInUserBuiltQueries - 1]` ?

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn On what line is the error?

Comment: Only after, techloverr and giammin suggestions have been implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are wrong

```
int itemsInUserBuiltQueries = UserBuiltQueries.Count();
UserBuiltQueries[itemsInUserBuiltQueries] = argFromQueryBuilder.ToString();
```

Arrays start at index zero and end at index (Count - 1), so, if  `UserBuiltQueries.Count()` returns 10 you could use indexes from 0 to 9. Essentially, using index 10, you are adding a new string outside the end of the array.

However, if your requirements force you to expand the array, it is better and more easy to code if you use a `List<string>` instead. Adding new elements will be a lot more easier and you could still use the List as an Array for common tasks.

```
    List<string> UserBuiltQueries = new List<string>();

    .....

    public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
    { 
        UserBuiltQueries.Add(argFromQueryBuilder);

        //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it.
        foreach (string query in UserBuiltQueries)
        {
            CheckBox checkQueries = new CheckBox() { Content = query };
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(checkQueries);
            checkboxes.Add(checkQueries);
        }
    }
```

By the way, you should stop to unnecessarily convert a string to a string. You pass a `ttextBox1.Text.ToString()`  but `ttextBox1.Text` is already a string. Inside the method the parameter `argFromQueryBuilder` is already a string and there is no need to convert to a string

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using string[] for UserBuildQueries, use List. When you need it as an array, you can simply say: UserBuildQueries.ToArry()

Rewrite the function to

```
public void DisplayCalcQuery(string argFromQueryBuilder)
{ 
  UserBuiltQueries.Add(argFromQueryBuilder.ToString());
  //displayng the user built query(queries) on the stack panel meant to display it.
  foreach (string query in UserBuiltQueries)
  {
     CheckBox checkQueries = new CheckBox() { Content = query };
     stackPanel1.Children.Add(checkQueries);
     checkboxes.Add(checkQueries);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# but I think in all programming language indexis start from 0:

so if an array has length or count =1 the index is 0 array[0], array.lenght==1

```
int itemsInUserBuiltQueries = UserBuiltQueries.Count()-1;
UserBuiltQueries[itemsInUserBuiltQueries] = argFromQueryBuilder.ToString();
```

And double check that your array is initialized before using it!